# Magid Mesharim: How is it that the angel knew Aramaic?

Tags: aramaic, malach-angel, jewish-books

There is a book called "magid mesharim" written by Maran Bet Yosef in Aramaic through the exact words of an angel. My issue with this is that we learned from some Gemaras ([Shabbat 12b](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=147&size=1) is one) that angels don't know Aramaic. How did the angel know Aramaic?

Comment: I just want to say this is an awesome question!

Comment: There are serious questions regading the authenticity of Maggid Mesharim.

Comment: R. Hai Gaon says that we dont hold like the whole Gemara about not praying to angels in Aramaic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Tosafot there (Shabbat 12b) writes that only the angel Gavriel knows Aramaic. This is probably the angel that taught Maran.

EDIT: I found a Ros"h in Berachot 2:2 that says it's not that they don't understand Aramaic, it simply is not favorable in their eyes. The Maadanei Yom Tov (note 7) ask a question that I won't bring up, but I will bring down what he says at the end Arabic would fall into the same category as Aramaic.